# A generalization of De Montfort's card problem

Tags: probability

Suppose that  you have two decks of cards. Each deck has $k$ kinds of cards and there are $s$ cards of each kind. The decks are shuffled thoroughly, and the orderings of the decks are compared. A match occurs when two cards of the same type occupy the same position in their respective decks.  For large $k$, the probability of no match is approximately equal to $e^{-s}$. I tried to find an exact formula, but I could not find one.

Comment: typo. It should be $k$